# posix threading in C condition variables

Tags: c, variables, pthreads, conditional-statements

I've done my share of reading of condition variables, and I am simply stuck not being able to comprehend on how to use them.

I have a tree, who as of now, when you make an insertion for a node which already exists, it returns 0, which implies it already exists hence failure.

I now want to extend pthreads support, where rather than mentioning it can not be done since it already exists and returns 0, I want it to be on a waiting queue, and once the requested node is deleted, go ahead and now insert.

For example,

Suppose a tree has 3 nodes, with value 1, 5, 10
If I want to insert a new node with value 10, rather than returning 0 and throwing an error that the value already exists, it should wait for the node with the value 10 to delete, once it is deleted, it should go back ahead and insert.

My insert function else block, which returns 0 after it has previously inspected that the node exists with that value, you can be assured that the logic of knowing it exists works fine, now I am simply trying to add the conditional variable support where it waits. The datafield condition is initialized at the first line of the insert, so that's done as well. I am now hoping that when it enters this block, the cond_wait is the only line of code which will be executed, and then it will simply wait till the delete signals it. Is my approach here right? If it is, in the delete, how do I signal it? Please help me out here, I have spent hours reading and looking at examples trying to figure this out.

Code,

```
  else

      {
        //IF DUPLICATE EXISTS
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        node->counter++;
        pthread_cond_wait(&node->condition, &m);
        _insert(string, strlen, ip4_address, node, NULL, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

        return 1;//I CHANGED IT FROM 0 to one, since if signalled, and if reached to this limit
        //it was probably successful

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A condition variable wait must be wrapped in a loop. The loop's guard tests a condition over the shared data protected by a mutex. It makes no sense to use a condition variable as you have it.

If it makes sense to wait for the node with value 10 to be deleted before inserting it, then it is done with logic like this:

```
lock(mutex)
while (tree.contains(key))
  wait(cond, mutex)
tree.insert(key, value)
unlock(mutex)
```

The other task does this:

```
lock(mutex)
tree.delete(key)
unlock(mutex)
broadcast(cond) // could be in the mutex, but better outside!
```

When C. A. R. Hoare invented monitors and condition variables, the original concept was a little different. Concerns about efficiency on multiple processors wasn't a concern, and so the following logic was supported:

```
enter(monitor);
if (tree.contains(key))   // no loop
  wait(cond, monitor)
tree.insert(key, value)
leave(monitor);
```

There was a guarantee that when the other task signals the condition, the waiting task will be atomically transferred back to the monitor without any other task being able to seize the monitor. So for instance when a task is in the monitor and deletes node 10, and signals the condition variable, the first task waiting on that condition variable is guaranteed to immediately get the monitor.  It is not that way with POSIX mutexes and conditions (for good reasons).

Another difference between mutexes and monitors is a thread does not have to hold the mutex to signal the condition variable. In fact, it is a good idea not to. Signaling a condition variable is potentially an expensive operation (trip to the kernel). Mutexes should guard critical regions which are as short as possible (just a few instructions, ideally) to minimize contention.

Yet another difference is that POSIX conditions have a `pthread_cond_broadcast` function which wakes up all threads waiting on a condition. This is always the correct function to use by default. In situations in which it it obvious (or can be shown that) waking up a single thread is correct, then the function `pthread_cond_signal` can be used to optimize the code.

Comment: why does it not make any sense? I will only enter that section if insertion of a node already exists in the tree, then be added to a queue. Example will help.

Comment: in particular, when a signal is invoked from delete, I don't understand where the thread resumes from. I would need to try to insert again, which means run the insert all over again.

Comment: Because the logical condition "if duplicate exists" can change at any time, since you are not holding a mutex! You have not evaluated that condition anywhere inside your mutex-protected region. The code just assumes it is true.

Comment: Any access to shared, mutable data without holding the mutex is a data race condition. If you evaluate `tree.contains()` without holding the mutex, it could crash because the data structure is in some intermediate state while another thread is inserting into it.

Comment: how can I use a single condition variable for all the nodes? Or are you simply on a delete invoking the condition to go check and see if it is now deleted?

Comment: The condition object just abstract a contact point for waiting and waking up waiting threads. It does not represent a specific logical condition which they are waiting for. In principle, a single condition variable can handle all situations where you need a wait/wakeup. Since all the threads re-check the condition they are interested in, there is no confusion, only inefficiency. If multiple logical conditions are tied to the same condition variable, you will almost certainly have to use `pthread_cond_broadcast`. Waking up just one thread will be incorrect, because it may not be the right one.

Comment: I used your appraoach, and it is not working as expected, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983023/condition-variable-not-working-as-expected-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Answer (score 1):

Here are assumptions:

```
struct tree
{
   ... // some other data (whatever)
   pthread_mutex_t mitex;
   pthread_cond_t  cond;
};
```

Helper function:

```
int tree_contains_value(struct tree *t, int value)
{
    return ...; // returns 0 or 1
}
```

And here is an insertion:

```
void tree_insert(struct tree *t, int val)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&t->mutex);
    while (tree_contains_value(t, value))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&t->cond, &t->mutex);
    }
    ... // do actual insert
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&t->mutex);
}
```

And removal:

```
void tree_remove(struct tree *t, int val)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&t->mutex);
    ... //remove value
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&t->cond); // notify all wating threads if any
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&t->mutex);
}
```

Comment: my question to you is when you do an insert, and the tree does contain the value, so it returns, 1 and then that node which was to be inserted is now in the cond_wait, does that interrupt the program? i.e, does the program which had that insert code function move on to the next line and places that on the queue? Then on the remove, when you notify all the threads, and the program is now on a different line, from where does the program execute? That is my main question, thanks!

Comment: @Ozymandy The insertion function will stay in the loop until the tree doesn't contain given value. I.e. on the first attempt the thread will be blocked and wait for the signal. When any value is removed, the remove thread wakes up all waiting threads (as I use only 1 condition variable), and continue. Each of the waken thread will check if the condition is 0 and then proceed. If there are several waiting on the same value, only the first one will succeed. If none is wating for the removed value, all threads will block again

Comment: but does the program's int main function continue executing or is the entire program blocked until that condition is met. I.e insert(node, 5), insert(node1, 5), now that node1 thread is waiting, and the 3rdline of code is delete(node,5), which will trigger node 1. I feel that the delete line of code won't even be called sine the program is waiting int that loop

Comment: @Ozymandy the main thread will be blocked. Until another thread removes the value from the tree. Apparently you missed the point: mutexes and condvars require threads, if you have a single-threaded application, they are not helpfull.